# Efficient way of transforming a ddiMatrix to Bigmatrix in R

Tags: matrix, bigdata, rcpp, memory-efficient

I've been trying, without success, to transform a ddiMatrix (diagonal matrix) into a Bigmatrix in R in an efficient way since my matrix is large.

The only way I manage to do it was passing it to matrix form first, and then converting it to a big.matrix form, as the example below.

```
library(Matrix)
library(bigmemory)

DM <- Diagonal(x = c(1,2,3,4)) 
DM <- as.big.matrix(as.matrix(DM))
```

This is very memory-consuming (therefore slow) as my benchmark metrics show.

Any idea? (Using Rcpp or anything else)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fear this may be unavoidable as you are converting from *sparse* to *dense* matrices.

Consider your example but with a slightly larger initial diagonal matrix, and an explicit intermediate step:

```
> sparseDM <- Matrix::Diagonal(x = as.numeric(1:100))
> denseM <- Matrix::as.matrix(sparseDM)
> bigM <- bigmemory::as.big.matrix(denseM)
> 
> dang::ls.objects()    # simple helper function in a package of mine
               Type  Size Rows Columns
bigM     big.matrix   696  100     100
denseM       matrix 80216  100     100
sparseDM  ddiMatrix  2040  100     100
>
```

As you can see, the sparse matrix is *much* smaller at 100 elements (plus some internal indexing) than the 100 x 100 dense matrix (with approximaly 100^2 * 8 bytes, plus the bit of `SEXP` overhead).  The `bigmemory` object then *looks small* to R because its allocation is outside of R, but as a *dense* matrix it is still stored with all the non-diagonal elements you don't really care about.

In short, it sounds like you want a 'bigmemory-alike sparse matrix' class. As far as I know, nobody has written one.

Comment: Thx, Dirk. Just for illustration, I will post an extra answer showing a way I found to avoid the usage of a ddiMatrix. Not sure if it is the best solution, but I will share it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I managed to do, avoiding a ddiMatrix format. I guess it only works for those who are looking to work with `big.matrix` exclusively.

```
library(bigmemory)

dim = 2
main.diag <- seq(from=1,to=dim,by=1)
BM0 <- big.matrix(dim, dim,init=0)
BM0[cbind(1:dim, 1:dim)] <- main.diag
BM0[]
```

A word of caution: initializing a big `big.matrix` can be very time-consuming.